# Анализ и выборка уникальных сообщений

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Просьба подсказать, как можно реализовать выборку по уникальным значениям, имея DF с текстовыми сообщениями.

Текст сообщений может содержать от 4 до 200+ символов, текстовые сообщение по типу: "Ваш ID 12345", "your ID 23432" или аналогичного характера, как на рус. так и на английском языке. Соответственно df с данными сообщениями может содержать от 100к до нескольки миллионов строк, где строка соответствует сообщению, необходимо проанализировать и получить по несколько уникальных примеров сообщений. Соответсвенно уникальными будут считаться, "Ваш ID xxxx", "your ID xxxx",. Соответсвенно DF может содержать различные шаблоны которые заранее не известны.

Входные данные:

```
---------------------
9089 | your ID 9897
9089 | is code 67567
9089 | code 90878
9089 | is code 67567
9089 | code 90878
8789 | code 78yh45
6078 | your ID is 908r78
7843 | Ваш ID 909r5
```

Нужно получить выборку уникальных сообщений в подобном формате по одному примеру каждого контента:

```
--------------------
9089 | your ID xxxx
9089 | is code xxxx
9089 | code xxxx
6078 | your ID is хххх
7843 | Ваш ID хххх
8789 | code ххххх
```

Comment: Если хотите получить ответ, отредактируйте свой вопрос в соответствии с рекомендациями: [mcve]

Comment: Вы хотите получить уникальные строки, отличающиеся только числами (ID) или задача более сложная и обширная? В последнем случае понадобится гораздо больше примеров в вопросе...

Comment: я думаю, автор вопроса пытается сделать задачу кластеризации, но только хочет, что бы какая то умная функция сама классифицировала его сообщения.

Comment: @KoVadim, завидую вашим телепатическим способностям)

Comment: да, мне нужно получить уникальные сообщения которые будут отличаться только числами ID, но DF может содержать всевозможные варианты сообщения,
возможно ли сделать данную выборку? можете подсказать в какую сторону искать?

Comment: если они могут отличатся только числовыми данными, то в чем проблема? пишем функцию, которая удаляет с строки все цифры. И теперь однотипные строки будут "одинаковые".

Comment: А как быть в случае если код будет состоять из комбинации цифр букв?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Любой набор строк будет минимальным набором данных. Так что Ваш ответ ниже просто имплементация моей идеи выше:)

Comment: @KoVadim, пока вы писали комментарий - параллельно я писал ответ, поэтому "ваша идея" не является уникальной :-)

Comment: @MaxU обновил, добавил входные-выходные данные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> да, мне нужно получить уникальные сообщения которые будут отличаться только числами ID

```
In [389]: df
Out[389]:
     ID                msg
0  9089       your ID 9897
1  9089      is code 67567
2  9089         code 90878
3  9089      is code 67567
4  9089         code 90878
5  8789        code 78yh45
6  6078  your ID is 908r78
7  7843       Ваш ID 909r5

In [390]: res = df["msg"].str.replace(r"\d[\da-z]{2,}", "XXXX").drop_duplicates()

In [391]: res
Out[391]:
0       your ID XXXX
1       is code XXXX
2          code XXXX
6    your ID is XXXX
7        Ваш ID XXXX
Name: msg, dtype: object
```